# jsp page cannot find javascript-Wrong path

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

I have in the folder WEB-INF/classes the servlet1.

Out of this folder I have a folder named js where inside in this, there is an another folder named first. So in the folder named first, there is my js ( inside in this js there is a url connected with the servlet1)

--js/first/myjav.js

This js is called in a jsp page. However when I m trying to run the jsp the js is not running. I think that the erro is the url path

**I m trying this :** url: '../servlet/Servlet1'

Can you please help me ?

Comment: Can you kindly post the HTML section of your JSP / Servlet, where you are "actually" linking to the JavaScript file?

Comment: in the jsp page i call the js by this  <script type="text/js" src="js/first/myjav.js"></script>

Comment: That looks good. So what's the URL of the JSP Page?

Comment: put your project structure and js content